# Mouse over fade in image on body's background

Tags: jquery, hover, background-image, fadein, fade

I'm working on a menu which show an image in full-screen when mouse over. I made it works for one, but it failed white multiples images.

The pictures squeezes and show also the fixed background between them. I managed the "squeezes" by adding a script for each pictures but doesn't seem right to do it that way and was also showing the fixed background between the pictures.

Any idea ? :)

HTML

```
<div id="corps">
<div id="sommaire">
    <div id="MENUalexia">Alexia</div>
        <div id="BGalexia"></div>
    <div id="MENUmeaudre">Méaudre</div>
        <div id="BGmeaudre"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#MENUalexia{
    padding: 80px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
#BGalexia{
    background: url("photos/bgalexia.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* pour Chrome et Safari */
    -moz-background-size: cover; /* pour Firefox */
    -o-background-size: cover; /* pour Opera */
    background-size: cover; /* version standardisÃƒÂ©e */
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
}
#MENUmeaudre{
     padding: 80px;
     top: 80px;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 2;
}
#BGmeaudre{
    background: url("photos/bgmeaudre.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* pour Chrome et Safari */
    -moz-background-size: cover; /* pour Firefox */
    -o-background-size: cover; /* pour Opera */
    background-size: cover; /* version standardisÃƒÂ©e */

   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('.div1').hover(function() { 
    $('.div2').fadeIn(); 
}, function() { 
    $('.div2').fadeOut(); 
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this, but not able to replicate: http://jsbin.com/cezibarica/edit?html,css,js,output Can you edit to show your problem?

Comment: Probably because he's using a jquery library, @Leshautsdurant please include which library you are using so we can replicate the bug

Comment: I'm using http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
Sorry, first time I ask for code.

Comment: Is it what you need ? @PraveenKumar 
Thanks :)